# How to insert "/" in the name of the content type in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I want to create one content type with name "General Information/General Services". But when I am trying to create it is throwing an error that special characters (in my case it is "/") are not allowed. For this I tried to insert with the ANSI character of slash. But `&` symbol is not allowing to enter. Any suggestion for this problem.
I added that screen shot for reference. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Content Type Name value can be a reference to a resource in the format **$Resources:String**.

For more information, see Localizing SharePoint Solutions. The name itself cannot be longer than 128 characters and cannot contain the characters \ / : * ? " # % < > { } | ~ &, two consecutive periods (..), or special characters, such as a tab.

Please see this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460224(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: The solution what you suggested here is for development side right!! But Can't we achieve through the user interface itself means from the site it self?

Comment: No we cant provide / in name of content type